# Android PdfRenderer in not getting initialised

Tags: java, android

I am trying out the PdfRenderer to display the PPT in my app.

I am using following code to initialize the PdfRenderer:

```
        ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = mContext.getAssets().openFd("sample.pdf").getParcelFileDescriptor();
        PdfRenderer renderer = null;
        renderer = new PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor);
```

Last line throws the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: not create document. Error: 
04-21 13:46:49.754 17589-17589 W/System.err: at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.nativeCreate(Native Method)
04-21 13:46:49.754 17589-17589 W/System.err:     at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.<init>(PdfRenderer.java:153)
```

I have searched the web for error but found nothing concrete. Any help on this would be appreciated. I have tried all the permutations of minSDKVersion :P

Comment: Facing same problem, were you able to solve it?

Comment: I had urgent requirement, I went for MuPdf instead. Its easy to integrate, only downside being it will increase your app size.